# How to csv export my catalogue in a different language on Pimcore?

Tags: pimcore

I simply need to csv export my catalogue in Spanish. Thus, I set the default language to Spanish in the system settings and reloaded the page.[image]

But, here in the data objects I still do not have Spanish as the current language[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

As Pimcore does not delete the data when you remove a language from the system settings, I removed all the languages but Spanish. And, exported the data in Spanish successfully.